# Removing a template with Blaze.remove() not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm adding a template in a tree () with:

```
var $monitor = $("ul#u-my-monitors");
var liData = {...};
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.uTreeLi, liData, $monitor[0], $monitor.find("li:last")[0]);
```

and then later on I remove it with:

```
Blaze.remove(Blaze.getView($("#u-monitors").find("li[data-target='" + $element.attr("id") + "']")[0]));
//$("#u-monitors li[data-target='" + $element.attr("id") + "']").remove();
```

Blaze.remove doesn't work but the jQuery version does.

am I missing something?

Comment: Does `Blaze.getView($("#u-monitors").find("li[data-target='" + $element.attr("id") + "']")[0])` definitely return the view in question?

Comment: yes, it does, this is very wierd! I also checked with `console.log(Blaze.getView($("#u-monitors").find("li[data-target='" + $element.attr("id") + "']")[0]))` and I can see the view

Comment: What version of Meteor are you using? If I remember correctly, older versions only clean up the reactivity with `Blaze.remove` and don't actually remove the DOM node.

Comment: I'm using the latest one (1.0.2.1) the funny thing is that I'm adding and removing templates in others places in the same project without problem

Comment: could you make a meteorpad.com showing the problem?

Comment: unfortunately I can't since I'm getting data from a private network and these templates depend on this data. I could paste just my code there if that help...

Answer (score 1):

Recently I bumped into this problem too. Instead of

```
var view = Blaze.getView($("#some-id");
Blaze.remove(view);
```

I did this:

```
var view = Blaze.getView($("#some-id"))[0];
Blaze.remove(view);
```

If you

> console.log($("#some-id"));

, it returns an array. Hope this helps.